# OkHttp is not caching responses on Android

Tags: android, retrofit, square, http-caching, okhttp

I am using retrofit 1.8.0, okhttp 2.1.0 and okhttp-urlconnection 2.1.0, I want to cache the responses I get from server and use them when there is no internet connection, this is my code:

```
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {

    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {

        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(HancoApplication.this)) {

            int maxAge = 60; // read from cache for 1 minute
            request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge);
        } else {

            int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
            request.addHeader("Cache-Control","public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale);
        }
    }
};
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
File cacheDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "responseCache");
Cache cache = null;
try {

    cache = new Cache(cacheDir, 1024 * 1024 * 12);
    okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(Const.API_URL).setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient)).setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor).build();
mWebApi = restAdapter.create(WebApi.class);
```

when I excute the same request without internet on the phone this is what it returns : 
HTTP/1.1 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)
OkHttp-Response-Source: NONE

I can't figure out whats wrong with my code, all the resources on the internet uses the same code!

Comment: What cache headers does your HTTP server return?

Comment: Those are all the headers I am getting from the server

Cache-Control: "max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate"
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 27 Nov 2014 08:14:46 GMT
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1417076086482
OkHttp-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1417076085965
Server: Cowboy
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Apiary-Ratelimit-Limit: 120
X-Apiary-Ratelimit-Remaining: 119
X-Apiary-Transaction-Id: 5476dd764c3ce90200a3be16

Comment: Your response says `must-revalidate` (so the server requires you call it) and your request says `only-if-cached` (so the client refuses to call the server). These are mutually incompatible.

Comment: (OkHttp has a feature request to disregard the server's headers; that'll be coming in a future release).

Comment: I changed the response from server to match your example in [link](https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/5889518) , the server now returns : Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, when I turn the wifi off the do the request again, an UnknownHostException is thrown. what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: How abount this @khaledsultan?

Comment: Simlar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321963/how-retrofit-with-okhttp-use-cache-data-when-offline/31606496#31606496