# How Retrofit with OKHttp use cache data when offline

Tags: android, caching, gzip, retrofit, okhttp

I want to Retrofit with OkHttp uses cache when is no Internet.

I prepare OkHttpClient like this:

```
    RestAdapter.Builder builder= new RestAdapter.Builder()
       .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;versions=1");
                if (MyApplicationUtils.isNetworkAvaliable(context)) {
                    int maxAge = 60; // read from cache for 1 minute
                    request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge);
                } else {
                    int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
                    request.addHeader("Cache-Control", 
                        "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale);
                }
            }
    });
```

and setting cache like this:

```
   Cache cache = null;
    try {
        cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("OKHttp", "Could not create http cache", e);
    }

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    if (cache != null) {
        okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
    }
```

and I checked on rooted device, that in cache directory are saving files with the "Response headers" and Gzip files.

But I don't get the correct answer from retrofit cache in offline, although in GZip file is coded my correct answer. So how can I make Retrofit can read GZip file and how can he know which file it should be (because I have a few files there with other responses) ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have simlar problem in my company :)

The problem was on server side. In serwer response i have:

```
Pragma: no-cache
```

So when i removed this everything starts working. Before i removed it i get all the time such exceptions: `504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)`

Ok so how implementation on my side looks.

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    File httpCacheDirectory = new File(appContext.getCacheDir(), "responses");

    Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, maxSizeInBytes);
    okHttpClient.setCache(cache);

    OkClient okClient = new OkClient(okHttpClient);

    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
    builder.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    builder.setClient(okClient);
```

If you have problems in testing on which side is problem (server or app). You can use such feauture to set headers received from server.

```
private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                               .removeHeader("Pragma")
                               .header("Cache-Control",
                                       String.format("max-age=%d", 60))
                               .build();
    }
};
```

and simply add it:

```
okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR);
```

Thanks to that as you can see i was able to remove `Pragma: no-cache` header for test time.

Also i suggest you to read about `Cache-Control` header:

[max-age](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3),[max-stale](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3)

Other usefull links:

[List of HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Avoiding_caching)

[Cache controll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache#Cache_control)

[Another sample code](https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/5889518)

Comment: You are the man!! You did not just save my day but saved two days :D.